# Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'

Tags: xml, powershell, sharepoint

I have a script that modifies xml file on sharepoint site. Script gets path to the given xml node, name of the node and value that it is supposed to put there. Then it uses Xelement.parse on value and puts it into the xml file on the site. For example:

```
\Script.ps1 -Mode AddOrUpdate -Path '/ParentNode/ChildNode' -Name 'InterestingRow' -Value '&lt;SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;/Search/SitePages/default.aspx?k={keyword}&lt;/SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;'
```

This one works as expected, but when i try to add:

```
&amp;peoplesearch=false
```

to the Value, so it would look like this:

```
&lt;SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;/Search/SitePages/default.aspx?k={keyword}&amp;peoplesearch=false&lt;/SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;
```

I get error as in the title, '=' is an unexpected token, expected token is ';'
There seems to be a problem with ampersand, but I used xml character entity code, so i really don't know what is going on here.

Code for parsing:

```
    try {
    if ($Mode -ne "Delete" -and $null -ne $Value -and $Value -ne '')
    {           
        $ValueXml = [XElement]::Parse($Value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the contents of `Script.ps1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be showing us escaped XML: that is, your value

```
&lt;SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;/Search/SitePages/default.aspx?k={keyword}&lt;/SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;
```

is an escaped representation of

```
<SearchCenterUrlSwitch>/Search/SitePages/default.aspx?k={keyword}</SearchCenterUrlSwitch>
```

Now if you change this to

```
&lt;SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;/Search/SitePages/default.aspx?k={keyword}&amp;peoplesearch=false&lt;/SearchCenterUrlSwitch&gt;
```

it becomes an escaped representation of

```
<SearchCenterUrlSwitch>/Search/SitePages/default.aspx?k={keyword}&peoplesearch=false</SearchCenterUrlSwitch>
```

which is not valid XML because it contains an unescaped ampersand.

So I think you need to double-escape the ampersand: it needs to be

`&amp;amp;peoplesearch=false`

Comment: Your suggestion did not work from the start, but it gave me an idea to wrap the part after slash in CDATA, which worked.